# Editing system files

Tags: permissions, sudo

Ive tried using `sudo gedit <filename>` but the terminal spits out "The owner of /home/user/.config/ibus/bus is not root!" as it opens gedit. Then when I try to save from gedit it comes up with an error at the top saying "could not save the file  
Unexpected error: Error writing to file: input/output error"

Comment: You may find this informative: [Why should users never use normal sudo to start graphical applications?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/270006/why-should-users-never-use-normal-sudo-to-start-graphical-applications)

Comment: You might want to see also http://www.webupd8.org/2015/03/how-to-run-gedit-and-nautilus-as-root.html, if applicable to your system.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest solution is to use [sudoedit](https://www.howtoforge.com/tutorial/how-to-let-users-securely-edit-files-using-sudoedit/) or [sudo -e](https://iwf1.com/meet-sudoedit-linux-tool-how-to-use-it-and-for-what-purpose) after adding your username to the [newsudo](https://www.howtogeek.com/50787/add-a-user-to-a-group-or-second-group-on-linux/) group w/ `sudo usermod -a -G newsudo yourusername` .

The classic answer you will find all over the web is to use gksudo or gksu to open a graphical editor, such as gedit.  However, gksudo and gksu are depreciated and no longer included with Debian and its derivatives, such as Ubuntu and Mint, [as noted by ItsFOSS](https://askubuntu.com/a/1047413/197910) and the previous web link.

[Nautilus Admin or PolicyKit](http://www.webupd8.org/2015/03/how-to-run-gedit-and-nautilus-as-root.html) can be used, as Bodo kindly noted above in Comments, if you are adamant you must have a graphical editor.

Comment: I used `sudo nano <filename>` and when it opened it showed that the document is blank. I copied the short file into the editor and made my changes, then when I went to save "[ Error writing <filename>: Permission denied ]" popped up on the bottom of the screen.

Comment: Hm, I can edit other files in the same directory(which are also read only), but for some reason the one file I want to edit won't open properly in nano.

Comment: @Daniel I suggest to show the command `ls -l <filename>` with its output in your question.

Comment: Please don’t suggest running an editor as root, it’s better to use `sudoedit` — and it can be set up to use a graphical editor, without requiring PolicyKit configuration.

Comment: Point well taken, answer revised accordingly.